# LINQ query not returning rows in string comparison

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to writing LINQ queries, and I'm having trouble with string comparisons. I'm loading the data into a DataTable (confirmed that table in SQL DB and DataTable have same number of rows), but for some reason I can't find a value that I know exists in both.

The text box contains 'servername' while the datarows contain 'servername.mydomain.net', so here's what my code looks like

```
string strParameter = txtAutoComplete.ToString().ToLower();

    //WUG TableAdapter and DataTable
    dsCIInfoTableAdapters.DeviceTableAdapter taWUG;
    taWUG = new dsCIInfoTableAdapters.DeviceTableAdapter();

    dsCIInfo.DeviceDataTable dtWUG = new dsCIInfo.DeviceDataTable();
    taWUG.Fill(dtWUG);

    var qstWUG = (from row in dtWUG.AsEnumerable()
                  where row.Field<string>("sDisplayName").ToLower().Contains(strParameter)
                  select row.Field<string>("sDisplayName"));
```

Comment: perhaps strParameter has extra spaces at the end or something, maybe try Trim() on it. And in linq statement do a string ==

Comment: Ahh i see its an auto complete, disregard the last portion about the string equality

Comment: It's really the where clause that's not working, if I take out the where clause there are 4426 rows returned, which is the same amount of rows in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I feel stupid... I forgot to use the textbox.text to assign it to a string

```
string strParameter = txtAutoComplete.Text.ToLower();


        //WUG TableAdapter and DataTable
        dsCIInfoTableAdapters.DeviceTableAdapter taWUG;
        taWUG = new dsCIInfoTableAdapters.DeviceTableAdapter();

        dsCIInfo.DeviceDataTable dtWUG = new dsCIInfo.DeviceDataTable();
        taWUG.Fill(dtWUG);

        var qstWUG = (from row in dtWUG.AsEnumerable()
                      let display = row.Field<string>("sDisplayName")
                      where display.ToLower().Contains(strParameter)
                      select display).ToArray();
```

Comment: Well dont feel bad I was sitting there looking at it and I missed it as well. Oh well glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Beleive in your LINQ statement dtWUG needs to be dtWUG.AsEnumerable().  Linq only works on data sources that implement the IEnumerable Interface.

Comment: Yeah his code should error, but it looks like its a DeviceDataTable... Whatever that is, perhaps it does implement IEnumerable

Comment: Sorry, in my haste to try and get something to work, I had removed that and it didn't make it to my code example here. I'm currently using .AsEnumerable() in my code

Comment: Ah I see, Are you looking to select that particular value only or the whole row object. You could try Select new { ServerName = p.Field<string>("sDisplayName") } .  Then when iterating on qstWUG you access server by qstWUG.Server.ToString(). if you need to whole row associated I would change it to select row. Then when Iterating you can access other field values associated with that server name.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it easier if you add some `let` statements where you can add breakpoints:

```
    var qstWUG = (from row in dtWUG
                  let display = row.Field<string>("sDisplayName")
                  let lower = display.ToLower()
                  let contains = lower.Contains(strParameter)
                  where contains
                  select display).ToArray();
```

Also convert it to an array using `.ToArray()` at the end, will make it execute immediately (LINQ is lazy by paradigm, doesn't execute until it's needed), and also easier to look at in subsequent breakpoints.